# Batch-File Variable Part of Another Variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Okay so let's say I have the following code

```
set playerlevel=5
set x=player
echo %x%level
```

I want the output to be "5", is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dbmitch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948072/4158862) is good for integers, but if you want to display strings *or* integers, you can simply use delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set playerlevel=5
set x=player
echo !%x%level!
```

Note that if the code is located inside of a code block (i.e. enclosed in parentheses), the syntax is slightly different.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM This is just an example code block to show off the alternate syntax with the %%s
for /L %%A in (1,1,1) do (
    set playerlevel=5
    set x=player
    call echo %%!x!level%%
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want by using a combination of `enabledelayedexpansion` and the `set /a` to emulate an EVAL function

> **Try this:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set playerlevel=5
set x=player

set /a varx = "%x%level"
echo %varx%
```